# ElasticSearch - how do I switch alias for rebuilding data index with new data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-elasticsearch

Basically what I want to do is rebuild ES cluster with new data with minimal downtime. After some researches, I realized it can be done using `alias` but I am not 100% sure about the exact action flow.

1. Let's say I have an index, `test1` in my ES and this index has `alias1` with bunch of data

> { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" }

2. And I want to create a new alias with a new index and rebuild the index with new data

> "actions" : [{ "add" : { "index" : "test2", "alias" : "alias2" } }]

3. Once rebuild in the new alias is done, switch the alias in the original index

> "actions" : [{ "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias2" } }]
>
> "actions" : [{ "remove" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } }]
>
> "actions" : [{ "remove_index" : { "index" : "test2" } }]

4. Then the index `test1` now starts indexing/querying from the new alias

=========================================================================

Q1. Is this the right way to rebuild/swap data in the index?

Q2. Does `remove` action hard-delete the data in the old alias, `alias1`?

Answer (score 4):

Devon,

The `actions` in Elastic's `_alias` allows you to pass an array of all actions you want to perform.

Here are my comments / suggestions :

- Creating an `alias2` is not required. `Aliases` are just like "pointers".
- Removing an `alias` won't remove the associated `indices` / data
- Removing an `index` from an `alias` won't remove the associated `indices` / data
- You can pass the `add` and `remove` actions in the same query so you don't have any downtime
- Here you forgot to add `test2` into `alias1` which would be use by your webservice / kibana / whatever

Query example :

```
curl -XPOST ${esUrl}/_aliases -d '{"actions":[{"remove" : {"index" : "*", "alias" : "${aliasName}"}},{"add" : { "index" : "${newIndex}", "alias" : "${aliasName}" }}]}'
```

Comment: I think there has been some misunderstandings. What I am trying to do is to have the same index name and change the pointer to other dataset. The existing code keeps accessing `test1` so I think `test1` should point to another alias. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: An index corresponds to a Dataset. So if you want to have a fresh view of your data, you should use only one alias, which points on your freshest index. At t0, your webservice should use alias1 which points on index1 and at t1, alias1 should point on index2. Aliases are only metadata (shortcuts) allowing to access specific indices (by union when more than 1 index).