# OpenSearch/ElasticSearch - Authorisation error removing alias using only a wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to do something fairly simple - I have an alias that may be associated with one or more indices and I want to remove all associations and add a single one. Here is an example of what I'm doing (as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585074/elasticsearch-how-do-i-switch-alias-for-rebuilding-data-index-with-new-data)):

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "*",          // or "index": "_all"
        "alias": "my_index"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "my_index_2023_01_05_17_18_29",
        "alias": "my_index"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using an admin user and for some reason I'm getting the following error message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "no permissions for [] and User [name=admin, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "no permissions for [] and User [name=admin, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=]"
  },
  "status" : 403
}
```

Kind of weird message - it doesn't specify what's the action that is failing (`no permissions for []`) so I cannot figure out which permissions I'm missing...

Either way, if instead of using the wildcard like that (`"index": "*"`), I do something like `"index": "my_index*"` it works - It is not exactly what I want but it executes.

Any idea why this might be happening and how can I solve this?

Thanks!

(Using OpenSearch 2.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify index_pattern as **"*"**, system indexes are also included. Even with the admin user, you cannot change the settings of the system indexes by default. You can delete the alias by using parameters like **"index_name*"** or **"*2022*"** instead of **"*"**.
For example:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "index_name*",
        "alias": "my_index"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit:
You can use the following API to remove all aliases without system indices.

```
DELETE *,.-*/_alias/my-alias
```

You can check if the API is correct before removing them

```
GET *,-.*/_alias/my-alias
```

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-alias.html

Note: Unfortunately, it's not possible to use an expression like `*,.-*` in the `POST _aliases` body.

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's what I'm currently doing as a workaround. The problem is that it doesn't cover all the cases. If there is an index associated that doesn't fit that naming pattern it won't remove it. Isn't there a way of selecting all except the system ones? Or maybe there is a naming convention for the system indices? - If there is I may be able to find a pattern to exclude those

Comment: Can you try this?
`DELETE *,.-*/_alias/my-alias`


https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-alias.html

Comment: You can check if the API is correct before remove them

`GET *,-.*/_alias/my-alias`

Comment: Doing a DELETE like that would indeed work, however I would need to make a POST request after that to add the new index. This would cause some small downtime. Seems like the only way of doing this would be to do a GET request first to fetch all the indices that are associated with the alias and then pass all those indices in the remove statement. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi again, You're welcome.
Unfortunately, it's not possible to use an expression like `*,.-*` in the `POST _aliases` body.
And yes, probably the way you mention will be your best solution for you case.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to update your comment with this information I can mark it as the solution

Comment: You're welcome :) comment updated.